# Call PHP function of a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

So I installed this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-table-editor/

In "how to install", it says I have to call the `add_db_table_editor` function in my theme’s functions.php in order for the plugin interface to show

Installing screenshot
[image]

I added this code at the very bottom of `functions.php` file, and when I refresh my website, it won't load.

This is my code (i'm very new to coding):

```
function add_db_table_editor(){

if(function_exists(‘add_db_table_editor’)){ add_db_table_editor(‘title=Employees&table=employees’);

add_db_table_editor(array( ‘title’=>’Test title’, ‘table’=>’wp_posts’, ‘sql’=>’SELECT));

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you have to go to

```
{wpinstallfolder}/wp-content/themes/{active_theme}
```

inside that active_theme folder you should find the

```
functions.php
```

Before you add any code to the functions.php you need to back it up, to revert back to in case you do not edit it properly.

Open it up and add the lines that the plugin told you to add. and save it.

This is a formated code block to help you

```
function add_db_table_editor(){
    if(function_exists('add_db_table_editor')){ 
        add_db_table_editor('title=Employees&table=employees');
        add_db_table_editor(array( 'title'=>'Test title', 'table'=>'wp_posts', 'sql'=>'SELECT * FROM event_registrations ORDER BY date_entered DESC'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you suggest and still i got same problem

Comment: @Mk1 the website wont load or the plugin wont load?

Comment: add_db_table_editor(array( ‘title’=>’Test title’, ‘table’=>’wp_posts’, ‘sql’=>’SELECT));
 needs to be  add_db_table_editor(array( ‘title’=>’Test title’, ‘table’=>’wp_posts’, ‘sql’=>’SELECT * FROM event_registrations ORDER BY date_entered DESC''));

Comment: @Mk1 Check my updated answer. The sql statment was not fully typed out in your question form the image, and it was missing a closing '

Comment: Yeah, I just copy pasted your code and still not working.
My whole website won't load, it's like there is a problem with the code.

Comment: Delete those lines from the functions.php file and reload your site.  I wouldn't trust a plugin that makes you manually edit your themes functions file.

Comment: Plugin is fine and well rated, and people seem to make it work (when you see comments and reviews)